# IDENTIFICAR Y REMOVER NUMEROS

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla con 2 campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven el campo **Csv** tiene lo siguiente **[4804300, 45, 4811044, 44, 4972440, 50, 5196488, 49]**

necesito quitar los corchetes y quitar el numero largo y que me quede solo los números que tienen dos
cifras  **45,44,50,49** al hacer el select, es decir solo mostrar los números que tienen dos cifras

he encontrado esta función que quita los caracteres y letras

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tblResultado1]
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO

SELECT [dbo].[tblResultado1](Csv) 
from [dbo].[tblResultado]
```

pero me quita las comas y los corchetes pero no he podido saber como mostrar solo los que tienen dos dígitos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una de las posibles opciones, quizá complicada, pero las funciones que te planteo, te servirán para muchos desarrollos.

Lo primero es separar el varchar por filas, y realizando el split por el carácter coma.

1. **Paso 1:** Split.

Existen muchas maneras de obtener un string spliteado, yo te propongo una que no utiliza cursores e iteraciones, no tiene limitaciones con los caracteres xml y es bastante potente. Eso si el código TSQL es complicado.

Para realizar el split utilizaremos dos funciones. La primera que nos devuelve ordenado los números que hay entre un rango definido por los parámetros @low y @high

[Get Nums Itzik Ben-Gan Solid Q](https://tsql.solidq.com/SourceCodes/GetNums.txt)

```
-- Itzik's VATN
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GetNums]
(@low AS bigint, @high AS bigint) 
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
WITH
L0 AS (SELECT c FROM (VALUES(1),(1)) AS D(c)),
L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
L5 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
(SELECT NULL)) AS rownum FROM L5)
SELECT TOP(@high - @low + 1) @low + rownum - 1 AS n
FROM Nums
ORDER BY rownum
);
```

La segunda para realizar el split, que utiliza como parte de ella a la primera. No puedo poner el enlace al autor, porque lo desconozco.

```
-- Erland's split_me
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_inline_split_me]
(
@param nvarchar(MAX), 
@delimiter nchar(1) = N','
)
RETURNS table AS
RETURN (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n) AS pos,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),
    SUBSTRING(@param, n,
    CHARINDEX(@delimiter, 
        @param + CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), 
    @delimiter), n) - n)))) 
    AS Value
FROM
    dbo.ufn_GetNums(1, LEN(@param))
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @delimiter) 
   + @param, n, 1) 
    = @delimiter
);
```

Con estas dos funciones obtendríamos sobre lo solicitado, algo tal que:

```
declare @csv varchar(250);
set @csv = '[4804300, 45, 4811044, 44, 4972440, 50, 5196488, 49]'
select  REPLACE((replace(fn.Value,'[','')),']','')
from dbo.ufn_inline_split_me(@csv,',') fn;
```

[image: Resultado paso 1]

Por tanto ya tenemos el paso 1 resuelto. Además si utilizamos la función replace, para eliminar los corchetes, solo nos quedan los números.

En el enlace tienes una explicación un poco más detallada de las dos funciones, o si tuvieses SQL Server 2016, la función string_split, que ya implementa el motor.

[Realizar un split](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/27/string-split-separar-cadenas/)

2. **Paso 2**

Montar las filas, como un solo valor. Como ya has visto la función stuff, pues escogemos esta para hacerlo.

```
declare @csv varchar(250);
set @csv = '[4804300, 45, 4811044, 44, 4972440, 50, 5196488, 49]'

Declare @result varchar(max);
select @result = STUFF(
( 
    Select ',' + 
            REPLACE((replace(fn.Value,'[','')),']','')
        from dbo.ufn_inline_split_me(@csv,',') fn
        where 
            len(REPLACE((replace(fn.Value,'[','')),']','')) = 2
for XML Path ('')),1,1,'');

Select @result
```

[image: Resultado2]

[Todas las filas en un solo resultado](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/11/todas-las-filas-de-una-columna-en-un-solo-resultado-2/)

Ahora que ya sabemos como hacer el proceso completo, crearemos una función que lo resuelva todo.

3. **Paso 3**

Creamos la función

```
Create function dbo.csvElementsWith2Chars(@csv varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
begin

Declare @result varchar(max);
select @result = STUFF(
( 
    Select ',' + 
            REPLACE((replace(fn.Value,'[','')),']','')
        from dbo.ufn_inline_split_me(@csv,',') fn
        where 
            len(REPLACE((replace(fn.Value,'[','')),']','')) = 2
for XML Path ('')),1,1,'');

return @result

End;
```

Y la invocamos tan fácil, como corresponde.

```
Create table dbo.resultados (id int, csv varchar(max))
GO
Insert into dbo.resultados (id, csv)
values
(1, '[4804300, 45, 4811044, 44, 4972440, 50, 5196488, 49]')
go
```

Con la tabla creada.

```
Select r.id, dbo.csvElementsWith2Chars(r.csv) as csv
from 
dbo.resultados r;
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias funciono correctamente