# IDENTIFICAR CARACTERES Y REMOVERLOS

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-12, postgresql-13

Tengo una tabla que contiene un campo el cual se llama CSV  de tipo varchar en este campo se almacena información de este tipo **"[4804300, 45, 4811044, 44, 4972440, 50, 5196488, 49]"**

Lo que necesito es de ese campo quitarle los **[ ]** y los números **4804300**, Únicamente deben de quedar los que son de 2 dígitos **45,44,50,49**  y luego sumarlos para obtener un promedio

He intentado con la función

```
select replace(csv, '[', '') from rating
```

También con `select substring(csv for 2) from rating;` con este logro hacer que únicamente lea 2 dígitos del campo pero no es lo que requiero ya que toma un valor diferente.

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Una curiosidad, es una tarea académica? hace unas horas apareció esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416145/identificar-y-remover-numeros para sql-server. Tal vez te ayude.

Comment: El valor almacenado coincide con la pregunta de `sql server`.

Comment: No, @PatricioMoracho el punto es que esa la encontre pero esta en sql server y esa misma estoy tratando de acoplarla a postgres y hasta el momento no logro hacer que funcione porque cambian algunas cosas

Comment: Lo que puede aprovechar es el concepto de la solución, la idea de "splitear" los valores para luego ver cuales de los números solo tienen longitud de 2.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si, eso estoy intentando hasta lograrlo, publique la pregunta porque puede ser que alguien responda... pero por ahora seguire intentando.. gracias!